# How can I find the path to an include in Symfony2?

Tags: include, symfony, twig, partials

I've looked thoroughly over Symfony related questions on this site but can't find the answer I need.

I'm using Symfony 2.0.9 with PHP 5.3.6 and my file structure looks like this:

```
src/
  Blog/
    TestBundle/
      Resources/
        views/
          Default/
            index.html.twig
            header.html.twig
```

Inside of index.html.twig I have:

```
<div id="header">
{% include "BlogTestBundle:Resources:Default:header.html.twig" %}
</div>
```

It keeps erroring out with

> Twig_error_loader: Unable to find template

no matter what I use for the path. Why isn't it finding the file? They're even in the same directory!

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should drop "Resources" from path.

Answer (score 18):

twig file includes should follow the format below:

```
FullBundleName:ControllerName:filename
```

You can also amend parts if they're not present, i.e. for just a file under a bundle /views directory you can use `FullBundleName::filename`

So in your case, use `BlogTestBundle:Default:header.html.twig`

Comment: **Awesome!** Thanks Inori - this actually worked. I used 

`BlogTestBundle:Default:header.html.twig`

strange that the full path doesn't work though.

Comment: I had the same problem, in my case, I wrote 'BlogTestBundle:DEFAULT:header.html.twig' (the equivalent), It worked on my Windows development computer, but the code broke on the deployment server because Linux is case sensitive. Just something to watch out!

Comment: this answer is correct but I also had the following problem:

I was trying to include a file which only contains macros, so I first named it using ``.twig`` extension and not ``.html.twig``, it didn't work.

It looks like that you **must** use the ``.html.twig`` extension, otherwise the file will not be found.